# InsertMany Document in a MongoDB Collection using C# BsonArray

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

How to Insert more than one document in a Single statement using InsertMany() MongoDB Method in C#

My MongoDB Database and Connections

```
IMongoClient _client;
IMongoDatabase _database;

_client = new MongoClient();
_database = _client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("EmpInfo");
```

I'm having a Collection - BsonArray

```
var EmpInfoArray = new BsonArray {
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {"EmpID", "100"},
        {"EmpName", "John"},
        {"EmpMobile", new BsonArray
                        {
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566610"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", false}
                            },
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566611"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", true} 
                            },
                        }
        },
        {"IsLive", true}
    },

    new BsonDocument
    {
        {"EmpID", "101"},
        {"EmpName", "Peter"},
        {"EmpMobile", new BsonArray
                        {
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566610"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", false}
                            },
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566611"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", false} 
                            },
                        }
        },
        {"IsLive", true}
    },

    new BsonDocument
    {
        {"EmpID", "102"},
        {"EmpName", "Jack"},
        {"EmpMobile", new BsonArray
                        {
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566610"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", true}
                            },
                            new BsonDocument { 
                                {"MobNumber", "55566611"}, 
                                {"IsPreferred", true}, 
                                {"IsLive", true} 
                            },
                        }
        },
        {"IsLive", false}
    }

}
```

The Insert Statement:

```
collection.InsertMany(EmpInfoArray);
```

In the above **`InsertMany()`** Extended method has a **build error**. Kindly assist me how to insert multiple records in a single statement execution using C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the build error is most probably because the `InsertMany` method is expecting a collection (`IEnumerable`,`List` or `Array`..) of BsonDocument instead of a `BsonArray`.

try :

```
var EmpInfoArray = new List<BsonDocument>() { //Changed BsonArray to List<BsonDocument>
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {"EmpID", "100"},
        {"EmpName", "John"},
        {"EmpMobile", new BsonArray
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: If this answer is correct please click on the tick sign to accept the answer :)

Comment: can you please answer for my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804551/multiple-logical-conditions-in-mongodb-select