# MongoDB C# Driver, httprequest.json to BSON, then insertMany

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, driver, bson

I want to replace a stock price data AccessDB with a MongoDB using MongoDB c# driver.

The download data using `xmlhttprequest` as `json` string is shown below (2 dates only):

```
 [{"date":"2016-01-04T00:00:00.000Z","close":2.77,"high":2.82,"low":2.63,"open":2.77,"volume":32516771},{"date":"2016-01-05T00:00:00.000Z","close":2.75,"high":2.8,"low":2.64,"open":2.77,"volume":12972260},....]
```

I have studied the c# driver documentation and conducted web searches, but can't find anything that I can get to work. I could parse the each document (i.e, price for a symbol and a date) in the `json` string and `insertOne` as in the `BsonDocument` snippet below.

I would think that `json` or `BSON` methods exist that make to appropriate conversions to accomplish a `BSON` `insertMany()` DB load.

Please help me get up the curve by finding appropriate info and learn how to do this.

Thank you.
    The below works with manual conversion from above JSON data for 1 date

```
BsonDocument stkDoc = new BsonDocument
    {
        {"symbol","AMD"},
        {"date","2016-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"},
        {"close",2.77},
        {"high",2.82},
        {"low",2.63},
        {"open",2.77},
        {"volume",32516771}
    };
    _client = new MongoClient();
    _db = _client.GetDatabase("stkprices");
    var collection = _db.GetCollection("stkdata1");
    collection.InsertOne(stkDoc);
```

Comment: If you want to [InsertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) you create a [collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802690/insertmany-document-in-a-mongodb-collection-using-c-sharp-bsonarray) of `BsonDocument`

Comment: Thank you suggesting creating a collection of BsonDocument (I used List<BsonDocument>) which I coded and it works.

Comment: Sorry, did not complete comment. Do you have suggestion on how to code json string deserialization for the BsonDocuments for the many dates? I manually coded my trial code.Thank you.

Comment: Subbu, thank you for your comment. It provided sufficient guidance for me to be able to insert my stock price data into my MongoDB database. And with appropriate info, it is not difficult or complex code. I could share this code, but there does not seem to be any interest in this community. Thanks again.